# how can optimize a sql query for being faster on big data?

Tags: mysql, sql

hi there I have table to store tags like this:

```
sate: publish:1 / unpublish:0

id | name | releated_content_id | state
1     a           1                 1
2     a           2                 1
3     a           3                 1
4     a           4                 1
5     b           1                 1
6     b           2                 1
7     b           3                 1  
8     c           1                 1
.
.
.
```

Now I try get first 7 name of most repeated tags with their counts.

I do it with this query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) count 
    FROM Tags 
    WHERE state = '1' 
    GROUP BY name 
    ORDER BY count 
    DESC LIMIT 7
```

It work well but it is too slow (more than 10 second to load)
becuase I have a big number of tags...around 1 million...

how can I optimized it?

any solution?

---

**Edit:**

@Allendar and @spencer7593 and @jlhonora

thanks for your answers...They are very helpfull for me...
But I do not which answer is the best...because of great notes and tests...

first one,index by state and then delete clauses ...it was very helpful...
but the average time became about 1 second...

is too much for my page load time (the average of my page load time is less 1 second...but it had a bad effect for first byte loading)

Finally I had to store the data in a file (every one hours via corn job) and then print data from file for every page load!...

thanks everyone.

Comment: Why do you `COUNT` too? Every matched record will contain the result count. You can't optimize the query a lot more. You need to make INDEXES precisely for this search query.

Comment: @Allendar you are correct , He is already having Limit 7 as well

Comment: `LIMIT` is a big illusion to what the MySQL engine really does tho. The whole table still needs to be traversed to find all `state` entries. Therefor he needs 2 INDEXES. 1.) for `name`, 2.) for `state` so they both get a BTREE index branching to quickly find the results through. The BTREE will cause the `1` `state` ID to be found instantly and the set will instantly be trimmed down insanely fast, resulting in much faster resolve times. LIMIT happens at the end of the query and has no performance impact, only memory impact.

Comment: @Allendar becuase I want print most repeated tags with their counts in a menu like this:   `<li>a(4)</li><li>b(3)</li>`

Comment: The query is fine. It's likely that you don't have an appropriate index defined. For this particular query, the most appropriate index would be a multi-column *covering* index, **`on Tags (state,name)`**. Note that   `state` should be the leading column (because of the equality predicate in the WHERE clause), immediately followed by the `name` column (because of the GROUP BY, and because MySQL can make use of the index to avoid an expensive sort operation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an INDEX on your `state` field. Here's why;

BTREE INDEX is made on the `state` field for *search-queries* (a.k.a. WHERE clauses). What will happen now is the BTREE will index your `state` values like so;

1 -> 11 -> 11 -> 112

2 -> 21 -> 22 -> 221

Now when you have, let's say 100k of your results being with `state` with ID `1`. It will ask the BTREE INDEX branch and starts with `1`. It doesn't need to go deeper because it already has found it. Under that branch it now instantly knows all the unique records it needs from your table and it will be blazing fast to find names based on your state.

For future references; if you also do WHERE on the `name` *and* `state`, then you need to make a combined INDEX on `name` and `state`, so the BTREE will combine a more complex INDEX of them both and will improve those queries too.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following: Add an index on the `name` column

Comment: Please explain `Why` as well.  As its a one line answer. Thanks

Comment: This answer is wrong and I'm not gonna down vote it, but still want to say that this is *not* the solution. You INDEX on `name`, but it's not used in WHERE, resulting in having no performance impact on his query. He needs a BTREE index on the `state` field, as that's the one you want to query on. The `name` field is just "selected" and does not need to be "inspected". That said, again, this will only slow down INSERTs into the table with no performance improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MySQL, create a composite index on `name` and `state`:

```
CREATE INDEX name_index ON Tags (state, name);
```

Kudos to @Allendar and @spencer7593 for getting it right.

**EDIT**: OK, I admit I may have jumped a bit fast on this one. So I made a script to test 4 scenarios:

1. No indexes
2. Index on name
3. Index on (state, name)
4. Index on state

TL;DR: The best one is **option 3**:

```
Results for tags
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  1.321065)
Results for tag_index_names
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.490763)
Results for tag_index_composites
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.151101)
Results for tag_index_states
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  1.289544)
```

Here's the full Ruby/ActiveRecord script for it:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'
require 'benchmark'

db_name = 'test_db'
# Change the following to reflect your database settings
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql2', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
  host:     'localhost',
  username: ENV['mysql_username'],
  database: db_name
)

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS #{db_name}")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE test_db")

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class TagIndexName < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class TagIndexComposite < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class TagIndexState < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# Define a minimal database schema
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:tags)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :tags, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :name
    t.integer :state
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:tag_index_names)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :tag_index_names, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :name, index: true
    t.integer :state
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:tag_index_states)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :tag_index_states, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :name
    t.integer :state, index: true
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:tag_index_composites)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :tag_index_composites, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :name
    t.integer :state
    t.index  [:state, :name]
  end
end

table_names = [Tag.table_name, TagIndexName.table_name, TagIndexComposite.table_name, TagIndexState.table_name]

table_names.each do |table_name|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name}")
end

puts "Creating items"
100000.times.each do |i|
  name = SecureRandom.hex
  state = Random.rand(2)
  Tag.new(name: name, state: state).save!
  TagIndexName.new(name: name, state: state).save!
  TagIndexComposite.new(name: name, state: state).save!
  TagIndexState.new(name: name, state: state).save!
  if i > 0 && (i % 10000) == 0
    print i
  end
end
puts "Done creating items"

iterations = 1
table_names.each do |table_name|
  puts "Results for #{table_name}"
  Benchmark.bm do |bm|
    bm.report do
      iterations.times do
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT name, COUNT(name) count FROM #{table_name} WHERE state = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 7")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please explain `Why` as well. As its a one line answer. Thanks .

Comment: Just as `AnalystCave.com` his answer, your answer is sadly wrong too.

Comment: The test results confirm the result we expect. The difference would be more pronounced with larger number of rows, and with longer rows. The multi-column index on **`(state,name)`** is a *covering* index for the query i.e. the query can be satisfied from the index pages, without any need for lookups to pages in the underlying table. And using the index, MySQL is able to avoid a sort operation to satisfy the GROUP BY... the `name` entries are already "in order" from the index.

Comment: The result with the index `on (state)` column would be much better if that column had a higher cardinality... that is, if that column was nearly unique, and we were pulling a small number of rows. But in that case, using an index `on (state,name)` would give equivalent performance. (Actually, any query that makes effective use of the index `on (state)` would be able to make equally effective use of the index `on (state,name)`. There would be no reason to have both indexes defined, the index on just the `state` column could be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular query, the most suitable index is a *covering* index.

```
  CREATE INDEX Tags_IX1 ON Tags (state, name)
```

We expect that the `EXPLAIN` output for your query would show this index being used, with "Using index" in the Extra column, and avoiding an expensive "Using filesort" operation.

Because there's an equality predicate on `state` in the WHERE clause, and then a group by operation on the `name` column, MySQL can satisfy the query from the index, without needing to do a "sort" operation, and without doing any lookup to pages in the underlying table.

The suggestions (in other answers) to create an index on just the `name` column are insufficient for best performance of this particular query.

If we created an index like this:

```
  ... ON Tags (name,state)
```

with `name` as the leading column, then we could re-write the query to make more effective use of that index:

```
  SELECT t.name
       , SUM(IF(t.state='1',t.name IS NOT NULL,NULL) AS count
    FROM Tags t
   GROUP BY t.name
   ORDER BY count DESC
   LIMIT 7
```

---

**EDIT**

Other answers here recommend adding an index on `state` column. It appears that `state` may have a low cardinality. That is, there are only a few values of that column, and a large percentage of the rows are going to have a value of `'1'`. In that case, an index on just `state` is not likely to give the best performance. That's because using that index (if MySQL even uses it) will require lookups to the underlying data pages to retrieve the `name` column, and then all of the rows will need to be sorted to satisfy the GROUP BY.

**Use the `EXPLAIN`, Luke.**

Reference: **8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html

---

**FOLLOWUP**

@Allendar claims (in comments to this answer) that this answer is wrong. He says that the covering index I recommend "will not improve performance", and says that an index on the single column `state` (as recommended in his answer) is the right answer. He also recommends running a test.

So, here's a test.

[**SQL Fiddle Here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20e73/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20e73/2)

(Be patient opening that SQL Fiddle link... it's populating a table of a million+ rows, building four indexes, and running fifteen queries, so it spins for a dozen seconds.)

Here are the results running MySQL 5.6 on my local machine:

```
run   no index     (state,name)  (name,state)  (state)      (name)
----  -----------  ------------  ------------  -----------  -----------
run1   2.410 sec    0.687 sec     1.076 sec     3.374 sec    3.924 sec
run2   2.433 sec    0.659 sec     1.074 sec     3.267 sec    3.958 sec
run3   2.851 sec    0.717 sec     1.024 sec     3.423 sec    4.222 sec
```

- Fastest was the multi-column index on `(state,name)`
- Second fastest was multi-column index on `(name,state)`
- Third fastest was full scan of the table
- Coming in fourth, slower than a table scan, is index on `(state)`
- And in last place, the index on just `(name)` column

From the run on SQL Fiddle, results were similar:

```
         none     (s,n)    (n,s)   (n)     (s)
 ----    ------   ------   ------  ------  ------
 run1     701ms    193ms    286ms  1462ms   959ms
 run2     707ms    191ms    282ms  1170ms   957ms
 run3     702ms    190ms    283ms  1157ms   914ms
```

The test results indicate that multi-column index on `(state,name)` is the winner.

Test results also indicate that a full table scan is *faster* than using an index on just the `state` column. That is, we get better performance by telling MySQL to *ignore* an index on just the `state` column.

Comment: This answer is also wrong; the WHERE statement he gives is not searching for `name`, only selecting it. Therefor adding a combined INDEX will slow down performance on big tables.

Comment: @Allendar: NO. MySQL can make use of the index to satisfy the `group by`, avoiding an expensive sort operation. The covering index will actually improve performance of this query. The downside the maintenance of the index as rows are inserted, updated, deleted.

Comment: That's not true. Try to test on it and it won't improve. You can add a separate INDEX on `name` so the GROUP BY can do *loosely indexing*, yet combining WHERE + GROUP BY in one INDEX has always caused slowdowns in either MySQL, MariaDB as Postgres in any project I worked on. So my response is *YES*, and either separate the INDEXes or either only use a single INDEX on `state` if write-operations are valuable on this table. Over-INDEXation is very costly...

Comment: @Allendar: results of test I ran confirm that *covering index* on `(state,name)` gives the best performance. Performance using an index on just the `(state)` column is actually *slower* than a full scan.